# On Mac : git push results in "requested URL returned error: 403"

Tags: git, github, http-status-code-403

On MacBook Pro. Trying to push out recent changes to repo.

```
$ git push origin master
remote: Permission to customer548repo/dbserver.git denied to krazyigor.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/customer548repo/dbserver.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: Have you authenticated properly? 403 is forbidden. Are you using the right url?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+The+requested+URL+returned+error%3A+403

Answer (score 0):

hat error means you are using wrong credential or wrong repo:

```
Username needs to be the user, not the email
Ensure you provide the proper password. If you have 2FA enabled on GitHub, you need to make sure you create an Access Token with proper access permissions and use the token as password instead.
Repo format is: https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git
```

403 means GitHub is not granting you access so one or more of the 3 things above are the problem